# Material Datepicker switching days with months on manual input

Tags: angular, angular-material

Material Datepicker switching days with months on manual input.

[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhQYx.gif)

I've tried everything I could find, every single parse/format adapter moment/date-fn stuff I could find.

Do you have any idea where might be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I just found it after a very long while, the problem was that in my MaterialModule kitchen-sink module I was providing a custom DateAdapter that was different from that of my RootModule, therefore the provided configuration was incorrect.